# Continuity of an upper semi-continuous function over periodic points

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, harmonic-analysis, limits-and-convergence

Let $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be an upper semi-continuous function on  $X$, which is a compact subspace of a vector space. Let sequence $x_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$, with positive elements - periodic: there exists such $p \in \mathbb{N}$, that for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $x_n=x_{n+p}$. It is easy to see that $$\bar{x}_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n} \to \frac{1}{p} \sum_{i=1}^p x_i.$$Assume that $f(\bar{x}_n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x_i)$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Is it true that $$ f(\bar{x_{n}}) \to \frac{1}{p}f(\sum_{i=1}^p x_i)?$$

Attempt: It is easy to see that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(\bar{x_{n}})  \leq f(\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^p x_i).$ On the other hand,

$$\bar{x}_n=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i=\frac{1}{n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p}\right\rfloor \sum_{i=1}^p x_i+\sum_{j=1}^{n \bmod p} x_i\right)=\frac{\lfloor n / p\rfloor}{n / p} \sum_{i=1}^p \frac{x_i}{p}+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n \bmod p} x_i.$$

Let $P=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n \bmod p} x_i.$ Therefore, by affinity,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} f(\bar{x_{n}})  \leq \frac{1}{p}f(\sum_{i=1}^p x_i) =\frac{1}{p}f(\sum_{i=1}^p x_i)+f(P)-f(P) = f(\bar{x_{n}})-  f(P).$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to not be true. For example, take $X = [0, 3]$, $x_n = 1$ for all odd $n$ and $2$ for all even $n$. Define $f$ to be the identity on $[1, 2]$, $f(3) = 10000$, and extend $f$ arbitrarily by continuity otherwise.

Trivially since $f$ is the identity on $[1, 2]$ your displayed equality holds for all $n$, however by continuity of $f$, we have $f(\bar x_n) \to f(\frac{3}{2}) = 1.5$, while the desired RHS is $\frac{1}{2} f(3) = 5000$.

Comment: Is your $X$ compact ?

Comment: It is not, though I'm not sure how a subspace of a vector space can be compact... anyhow I'll replace it with $X = [0, 3]$.

Comment: A stupid question: Why $f$ is continuous ?

Comment: Well you can define it to be any continuous function taking those values. For example $f(x) = x$ on $[0, 2]$, $f(x) = 9998x - 19994$ on $(2, 3]$.